# Connection between two android devices on different networks

Tags: java, android, network-programming

we have two android device A and B on different network and different IPs, we donot know the phone number of device A.Device B want to connect with device A i only know the application ID of the android Device A and Device installed the app and connected to internet. is there any technique to find device A on network through his application iD in a secured way using java language?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this question so far? Have you explored any possible classes or Googled around for similar solutions to a subset of the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)?